# Selenium and scalaTest error

Tags: scala, selenium, sbt, scalatest

i have a problem,

I'm trying to follow a chapter 5 of the book "sbt in Action"
And i have a problem that i don't understand what is wrong...

this is my SeleniumSpec.scala

```
package org.preownedkittens;

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import org.scalatest.events._
import org.scalatest.selenium._
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver


import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import org.scalatest.events._
import org.scalatest.selenium._
import org.scalatest.junit._
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

class SeleniumSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll with Chrome {
  val homePage: String = "http://localhost:9000"

  "Home page" should "redirect to kitten list" in {
    go to "http://localhost:9000"
    currentUrl should startWith ("http://localhost:9000/kittens")
  }

  it should "show three dropdown lists of attributes in sorted order" in {
    def select(name: String) = findAll(xpath("//select[@name='" + name + "']/option")).map { _.text }.toList
    def assertListCompleteAndIsSorted(list: Seq[String]) = {
      list.size should be(20)
      list.sorted should be(list)
    }

    go to homePage + "/kittens"

    assertListCompleteAndIsSorted(select("select1"))
    assertListCompleteAndIsSorted(select("select2"))
    assertListCompleteAndIsSorted(select("select3"))
  }

  private def purchaseForms() = findAll(xpath("//form/li/input[@id='purchase']/..")).map { _.text }.toList

  override def afterAll() {
    webDriver.quit()
  }
}
```

and when i execute the test, i have this error:

```
[info] SeleniumSpec:
[info] Home page
[info] - should redirect to kitten list *** FAILED ***
[info]   "http://localhost:9000/" did not start with substring "http://localhost:9000/kittens" (SeleniumSpec.scala:22)
[info] - should show three dropdown lists of attributes in sorted order *** FAILED ***
[info]   0 was not equal to 20 (SeleniumSpec.scala:28)
[info] Run completed in 4 seconds, 585 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 2, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 2 TESTS FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     org.preownedkittens.SeleniumSpec
[error] (website/it:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 19 s, completed 20-feb-2016 11:51:48
```

I have the chrome drive updated, (chrome app start but after second it close and the error appears)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your "Home Page" test goes to `http://localhost:9000`, but without any redirect (there is one in your next test) your `currentUrl should startWith` check correctly fails because of the URL mismatch.

Your "show three dropdown lists" test is probably failing because you're [not waiting](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-wait-examples) - after the `go to homePage + "/kittens"` request - for the page to fully load before (milliseconds later) your XPath queries run and return the number of matching elements. Zero is a quite plausible result if the page is only partially loaded.

Probably the best solution is to identify another element that should appear on the page in question (perhaps a footer?) and wait for *it* to appear:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000);  // 2 secs
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

At which point you can assume the page is fully loaded, and check the actual dropdown counts.

Comment: if you see this link: https://github.com/jsuereth/sbt-in-action-examples/tree/master/chapter5 - I'm following this book but this chapter doesn't work with Selenium. Can you help me?

Comment: I've just answered the question you asked. Did it help? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sorry, but your answer doesn't help me. I try to insert your code just in line 33, and it doesnt work, what should i do ?
https://github.com/jsuereth/sbt-in-action-examples/blob/master/chapter5/website/src/it/scala/SeleniumSpec.scala

Comment: I'm volunteering my free time to help you, so could you please clarify what doesn't work (with error messages) or what you don't understand about my explanation?

Comment: on the code, after import: import org.openqa.selenium.Keys - 
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType - 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions - 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait - I see that locator can not be resolved

Comment: 'locator' is just a placeholder for a lookup for something whose existing proves your page has fully loaded, e.g. `xpath("//footer")`. As I said, once you can prove your page has loaded, then you can start counting matches.

Answer (score 0):

you have a not started webdriver:

> ```
>           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin\\chromedriver.exe")
>
>     val dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
>     wd = new ChromeDriver(dc) // manage chrome through chromedriver
>     //    wd.get(host)  or go to host
>     //    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
>     //    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
> ```